# Unable to ping my remote machine through Ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

I am trying to ***ping*** my remote linux machine using the following command :

```
ansible remote -m ping -vvvv
```

I get the following response :

```
[root@ansible ansible]# ansible remote -m ping -vvvv
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
Loaded callback minimal of type stdout, v2.0
<192.41.50.9> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<192.41.50.9> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o Port=22 -o User=root -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r 192.41.50.9 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1480431200.39-212981181831507 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1480431200.39-212981181831507="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1480431200.39-212981181831507 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
192.41.50.9 | UNREACHABLE! => {
"changed": false,
"msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.",
"unreachable": true
}
```

My ***hosts file*** looks like this :

```
[remote]
192.41.50.9

[remote:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=root
ansible_ssh_pass=p@ssw0rd
ansible_ssh_port=22
```

When I tried to ssh into my remote machine, this is what i got :

```
[root@ansible ansible]# ssh root@192.41.50.9
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
86:d2:ca:8e:aa:8a:ce:25:c7:e5:31:7e:2a:c0:11:7f.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:3
RSA host key for 192.41.50.9 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

What might be the reason for this ***connection failure***?

Comment: can you run `ansible remote -m ping -vvvv` and paste the results here ?

Comment: I have changed my question and displayed the response when I type ***ansible remote -m ping -vvvv***. Please check it out. Thank you.

Comment: can you `ssh root@192.41.50.9` from the terminal ?

Comment: I have changed my question and displayed the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the output of the shell ssh, you'll find that

1. you are being attached by a man-in-the-middle attack (very unlikely)
2. the ssh key on the server has changed (because you re-created it and kept the same IP).

If your case is the latter one, you can add the following section in your ansible configuration file `ansible.cfg`

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking=False
```

Comment: I got the same error again. One of my colleagues has done something with **.rsa pub** files as I could not connect. I think that's the problem. Thank you for your valuable suggestions. I will try changing my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment or upvote but user2599522 has your answer, or at least one of them.

Assuming you are using root and always trying on 192.41.50.9 host, run:

```
ssh-keygen -f "/root/.ssh/known_hosts" -R 192.41.50.9
```

This will remove the previous fingerprint and let you accept the new one.
The reason is exactly what he stated.

Also, his solution is a permanent one. Using it is good for development because it always apply. The one I suggested will work once, until you change the host again.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the public ip with my private ip and it worked well. Now, I am able to ping my remote machine properly.